# Using slicing in multidimensional array as a variable

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

If the array is 1D, we can simply use the `slice` function. What if I want to do it for a multidimensional array?
For example, the slice I want is `[1,:,-5:,10]`, and I want to apply it to different arrays I have. Is there a simple way to achieve the following result?

```py
a = slice([1,:,-5:,10])
array1_sliced = array1[a]
array2_sliced = array2[a]
```

Currently I am getting the following error

> File "", line 1
>
> ```
> indices = slice([1,:,-5:,10])
>                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: `a = np.s_[1,:,-5:,10]`? Without a [MRE] it's hard to answer.

Comment: Yes, it works for both numpy arrays and torch tensors!